# EXP point system for actions on website

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, user-experience

So I need to create a function that is called every time a user completes an action, and then according to their action gives them exp points.

Currently I have something like this:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO experience (userid, action, exp) VALUES (1, $some_action, $exp)");
```

Just wondering what the best way to keep track of what they've achieved and such? Also would it be okay to use the SUM function to calculate their exp according to these records? Or would it be too slow if there are a lot of records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add a timestamp or datetime field, but yeah SUM would be the solution:

```
$qry = "SELECT userid, SUM(exp) FROM experience WHERE userid = 9999"
```

On a per-action breakdown:

```
$qry = "SELECT userid, action, SUM(exp) FROM experience WHERE userid = 9999 GROUP BY action"
```

Comment: Okay that's helpful. I think the dilemma I had when thinking it through is that I also have to link a notifications system with an EXP system, so I need to keep track of what they do as well as what they earn.

Comment: If you want more complex data on the actions, you could have a separate table for them, and a foreign key in the 'experience' table - so the 'actions' table would have 'action name', 'action type', 'action value' And, if you feel my answer was helpful, feel free to vote it up :)